# Right-to-left footnotes with RTL lemmata and LTR text with reledmac

Tags: reledmac, reledpar

What I want to happen is, with `reledmac` and `reledpar`, that critical footnotes to my RTL (Hebrew) column would have RTL notes Hebrew lemmata and English LTR content. (And I'll throw in an opposite-facing bracket separator too.)

I tried using different combinations of `\Xbhookgroup`, `\Xcolalign` (although I think this is only if my footnotes are already set in columns), and `\Xwrapcontent`, but nothing is coming out the I want it.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Ezra SIL}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\usepackage{bidi}

\begin{document}

\begin{pairs}

\begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart
        Column 1. The text of this column carries over into a second line.
    \pend
    \endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\selectlanguage{hebrew}
\begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart
        עמוד \edtext{ב׳.}{\Afootnote{Footnote.}} הטקסט של העמוד הזה נמשך לשורה שנייה.
    \pend
    \endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which engines do you use? Have look on the many question of stackexchange which deal with RTL and reledmac?

Comment: Yes I looked at the other questions, that's how I found out about some of the commands I tried. Nothing is working precisely the way I want.

Comment: and what engine do you use?

Comment: that: do you use xelatex or lualatex. Please provides a MWE in your question.

Comment: I use xelatex. I added a MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, notes that in your MWE, hebrew text is already right-to-left, with footnote content left-to-right, and with reversed bracked (because your footnotes is typeset with Ezra SIL. What you wanted, I think, is to have your footnote starting on right, as if there were a hebrew text.

After having loaded both reledmac and bidi, add these lines in your preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\let\footnoteruleA=\right@footnoterule
\let\Afootnoterule=\right@footnoterule
\makeatother

\Xbeforeinserting{\RTL}
```

The first line make the footnote rule to be right aligned. `\right@footnoterule` is provided by bidi. As there is a `@` in its name, we use `\makeatletter`.

`\Xbeforeinserting{\RTL}` tell that before a footnote is added by reledmac on the list of footnotes, it is set right-to-left.

Note that we must make a distinction between the time a footnote is added in the list of footnote (or, more precisly, on the box devoted to footnote), and the time footnotes are effectivly printed (what you tried, insucessfull, with `\Xbhookgroup`).

Ps: as you use right-to-left text, you need more runs to get the good line number in apparatus. Use latexmk to be sur to use the good number of runs.

Comment: \Xbeforeinserting worked for me, thank you. But the code to move the footnote rule just made the line disappear. Do you know what might be causing that?

Comment: You must add it after loading bidi. If you call it before, it diseapar.

Comment: you'r welcome. Don't forget also to vote up, and not only to mark the answer as ok.